# how to predict multiple outputs with keras model?

Tags: arrays, keras, typeerror, prediction

i have a h5 model with 2 dense outputs.

i wanted to predict the values with a single camera but i got this error message.

```
degree = float(model.predict(image, batch_size=1))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

the predict values must be 2 so i guess it's a dimension problem because it did work well with a model file which has 1 dense output.

I tried put np.array before model.predict but i got a same error message.

How should i change the prediction code?

Comment: I also tried with batch_size=2 but got a same message

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a vector to float?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro because i want to save the values in csv file to plotting line graph

Comment: Yes sure but its a vector, the values inside are float

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro yes but if i dont write float the values are with cramps like [[xx.xxx]] which i have to remove

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I decided to remove through afterwork. Thanks for your reply!